# Zoom locked to 3D cursor

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow

So here's the problem: Regardless of whether I have "*zoom to mouse position*" checked or not, for my view is zooming to the 3D cursor. I am running **2.77**, and I feel it is important to mention that this is *only occurring* in the 3D views. I cannot figure this out for the life of me so someone please help, it is getting annoying, especially when zooming way in.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you may have accidentally enabled *Lock to cursor* in *3D view > Properties region > View*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Blender 3.x. Click anywhere in 3D viewport, press <kbd>N</kbd>. Docked menu pops out. In the *View* tab, *View Lock* section, untick *Lock to 3D Cursor*.

That should be it. You should now be able to change navigation options in your preferences.